# Call JavaScript dynamically on Visual Web Part

Tags: javascript, web-part, jquery, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I currently have a visual web part that displays clocks from different time zones, using the jClocksGMT library as provided [here](http://kingkode.com/jclocksgmt-js/) in the .ascx file. However, instead of hardcoding the timezones I want to be able to pass the correct GMT values from the .ascx.cs file and have the clocks update accordingly. However I can't seem to find a straight answer for how to do this. How is it done?

Here is an example of the code from my .ascx file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jClocksGMT v. 2.0</title>        
        <style>
            body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
        </style>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev/Style%20Library/jClocksGMT-master/css/jclocksGMT.css"/>
        <script type="text/css" src="http://dev/Style%20Library/jClocksGMT-master/css/jClocksGMT.css"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev/Style%20Library/jClocksGMT-master/js/jClocksGMT.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev/Style%20Library/jClocksGMT-master/js/jquery.rotate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="clock_city"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(

                function () {
                    $('#clock_city').jClocksGMT(
                    {
                        title: 'City, USA',
                        offset: '-7' // <-- Value I want to change via .ascx.cs file
                        //imgpath: 'http://dev/Style Library/jClockGMT-master/'
                    });

                }
            )
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: What I mean is that I do not know how to update the values via client-side. Once I have the correct offset value in the .ascx.cs file, how do I get it into the client-side jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't easily grab the offset via client side, use a hidden field on the web part and populate it in C#. Then in client side code, grab the value of that field via jQuery and use it to power the jClocksGMT call.

```
$('#clock_city').jClocksGMT(
  {
      title: 'City, USA',
      offset: $("#lblTimeZone").text()
      //imgpath: 'http://dev/Style Library/jClockGMT-master/'
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean adding a Label to the web part and picking it up with the ascx.cs file, or something different? When I add a Label edit it with the .ascx.cs file the jQuery doesn't seem to pick anything up and the "offset" field is blank.

Comment: a Label will work but there's also a HiddenField object for just this purpose. You'll hve the figure ou the jQuery selector for that but it'll be there. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield?view=netframework-4.7.2